# How can I shift the elements of an Array to the order I desire?

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I'm working on a problem that says "Given an array of N items, take the item from the first position and arrange the array such that the item in its final ordered position and all of the items <= to that item come before it and all of the items >= come after it. The list is not sorted. Only one item is in its final order." What I am trying to do is sort an array so the I get the elements that are smaller than or equal to the element at array[0] to be in the array first then a[0], and at the end of the array should the elements that are greater than or equal to array[0]. For Example, if I have an array of 10 numbers like this "[3, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 1, 9, 5, 9]" My new array should be "[2, 1, 1, 3, 8, 9, 5, 9, 5, 9]". I've tried writing the code below but it doesn't work as it should. The output I get is instead [3, 5, 1, 2, 9, 9, 1, 9, 8, 5]. Can someone help me figure out how to fix this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] d = createRandomIntArray(10);
        System.out.println("Original Array: " + Arrays.toString(d));
        changeOrder(d);
        System.out.println("New Array: " + Arrays.toString(d));
    }

    public static int[] createRandomIntArray(int n) {
        Random random = new Random();

        int[] result = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            result[i] = random.nextInt(n);

        return result;
    }

    public static void swap(int[] x, int i, int j) {
        int temp = x[i];
        x[i] = x[j];
        x[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void changeOrder(int[] array) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[0] <= array[i + 1]) {
                swap(array, array[0], array[count++]);
            } else if (array[0] >= array[i + 1]) {
                swap(array, array[i + 1], array[array.length - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "*does not work*" mean? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], as we as expected and observed output.

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting entire programs into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus to an exact problem and remove all code not directly relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the algorithm should be reconsidered just to move the lower elements *before* the *head* element starting at position 0:

- if current element is less than head, *rotate* all elements from `head` to current position to the right by 1.

Example implementation:

```java
static void arrange(int[] arr) {
    int head = 0;
    for (int i = head + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[head]) {
            rotate(arr, head, i);
            head++;
        }
    }
}

static void rotate(int[] arr, int head, int i) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    for (int j = i; j > head; j--) {
        arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
    }
    arr[head] = tmp;
}
```

Test:

```java
int[] arr = {3, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 1, 9, 5, 9};
System.out.println("before: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
arrange(arr);
System.out.println("after:  " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
before: [3, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 1, 9, 5, 9]
after:  [2, 1, 1, 3, 8, 9, 5, 9, 5, 9]
```

---

```java
int[] arr = {9, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 1, 9, 5, 9};
System.out.println("before: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
arrange(arr);
System.out.println("after:  " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
before: [9, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 1, 9, 5, 9]
after:  [2, 8, 1, 5, 1, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```